# Script to change text colours on hover works in Firefox but not other browsers

Tags: jquery, cross-browser, click, hover

I have the following script which randomly assigns different colours (from an array) to letters in a DIV and changes these colours on hover.  The script is supposed to change the colours back when the mouse leaves the DIV (i.e. when no hover). It is doing so in Firefox, but not in other browsers (Safari, Chrome and IE).  Also the click function isn't working properly in these browsers either (again it is in Firefox).

You can see the script in action [here](http://monthlymixup.com/test.html).

I wonder if someone can help troubleshoot this?

Thanks,

Nick

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var test = $("#example p").text().split('');

    var normal = generateColors(test);
    var hover = generateColors(test);
    $("#example p").html(normal);

    $("#example").hover( 
      function(event) { $("#example p").html(hover) }, 
      function(event) { $("#example p").html(normal) });

    $("#example").click(function() { 
    location.href = "http://www.google.co.uk"; 
    });

});

function generateColors(characters) {
    var result = "";
    var i = 0;
    for(i=0; i < characters.length; i++) {
        result += "<span style='color:"+getColor()+"'>"+characters[i]+"</span>";
    }

   return result;
}        

function getColor() {
    var colList = ['#7EA404', '#14AFB0','#B05718', '#B0A914', '#B01617','#902BB0', '#B003A2', '#4A429C','#33821E', '#226795', '#D0B600','#886833'];

    var i = Math.floor((Math.random()*colList.length));
  return colList[i];
}
```

Comment: Seems fine to me  http://jsfiddle.net/F65AM/

Comment: Works ok here in FF12, Chrome 18, IE9, Safari 5.1.5 and Opera 11.51

Comment: Okay, looking at your example page, it appears to have something to do with the `font-face`.  You should include that in your question.  If you remove the font-face it works fine.

Comment: Mmmh, can it be something to do with the computer I'm using (a Mac?) - I'm running the latest versions of browsers

Comment: @Nick im using a Mac - and it works fine for me in Chrome and Firefox

Comment: @JamesMontagne I have now removed font-face and it's still not working at my end

Comment: @ManseUK Thanks - wonder what it could be?

Comment: @Nick look at James Montagne's comment above - seems to be connected with `font-face`

Comment: @ManseUK I have removed font-face and still am experiencing the same issue.  I see the same issue with the JSfiddle James set up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that it's not always picking up the mouseleave event when you're hovering over text. The simplest solution is to add padding to the div so that there is space between the text and the edge of the container. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6aLmL/1/)

Comment: Hoorah! That seems to fix it.  I'll do a bit more testing before confirming